# Live stream prerecorded video to YouTube using FFMPEG with 4500 kbps bitrate

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, stream, streaming

I tried various ways to make a live streaming script with a bit rate according to YouTube's recommendation of 4500 Kbps bit rate.
The code:

`ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i live1.mp4 -c copy -preset veryfast -b:v 7000k -maxrate 3000k -bufsize 6000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f flv -flvflags no_duration_filesize rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/(streamkey)`

and in my current code, there is an error when live: Use a keyframe frequency of four seconds or less. Currently, keyframes are sent infrequently which can cause buffering. The current keyframe frequency is 5.0 seconds. Please note that errors in the transfer process can cause the size of the GOP (group of images) to be incorrect.

How to fix my code?

I've tried several ways, but the bit rate is still high, and the error is in YouTube Studio

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to use it when no_duration_filesize removed. I use .mov format